# Get start and end date of the financial year in Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, math, php-carbon

I need to dynamically echo the start and end dates of the current Australian financial year (July 1st to June 30 of the year).

I am using Carbon and Laravel to get the dates of the current financial year.

I assume the code will look something like this semi-pseudocode

```
$now = now();
if( $now > $july_first_current_year ) {
    $year_start = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $now->subYear()->year . '-7-1 0:00:01');
    $year_end = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $now->year . '-6-30 0:00:01');
} else {
    $year_start = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $now->year . '-7-1 0:00:01');
    $year_end = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $now->addYear()->year . '-6-30 0:00:01');
}
```

As you can see my math is not quite right and it seems im missing a step or two to output the right dates. Or perhaps im missing something simple?

Comment: It seems to me you've reversed the logic. If you're past July 1st, that's where you want the current year as start and next year as end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $start_year = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', date('Y').'-07-01 00:00:00');
 $end_year = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', date('Y').'-06-30 23:59:59.999999');

 if(now() > $start_year)        
     $start_year = $start_year->subYear(1);        
 else
     $end_year = $end_year->addYear(1);
```

Comment: This worked thankyou. I had to reverse the `now() > $start_year` to `now() < $start_year` though so that it would be the current financial year rather than the next one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [carbon helper](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation) function for getting first of july

The result is something like below code:

```
$now = now();
if ($now > new Carbon('first day of July ' . date('Y'), 'Australia/Adelaide')) {
    $year_start = $now->subYear()->month(7)->day(1)->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0)->format('Y-m-d H:s:i');
    $year_end   = $now->month(6)->day(30)->minute(0)->second(0)->format('Y-m-d H:s:i');
} else {
    $year_start = $now->month(7)->day(1)->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0)->format('Y-m-d H:s:i');
    $year_end   = $now->addYear()->month(6)->day(30)->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0)->format('Y-m-d H:s:i');
}
```

Comment: month in his case must be always 7 and 6 
if you use `$now->addMonths(7)` won't work

Comment: @PsyLogic I've updated answer to give fixed month, hour, minute and second

Answer (score 0):

An slightly cleaner and more readable solution using Carbon can be like this:

```php
$start = (new Carbon('first day of September'))->startOfDay();
$end = (new Carbon('last day of October'))->endOfDay();
(now() < $start) ? $start = $start->subYear() : $end = $end->addYear();
```

Current timezone can be set in `config/app.php` of Laravel but you can also override it with Carbon like `new Carbon('first day of September', 'Australia/Sydney')`.

Also for testing purposes you can use `setTimeNow` of Carbon to test `start` and `end` date of your fiscal year:

```php
Carbon::setTestNow(now()->subYear()->addMonths(7)->subDays(15));

dd(now(), $start, $end); // or assert it in your phpunit tests.
```